# Raspberry Pi 2 model B both lights on

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have a problem that began recently, I had my RPi totally configured 3 or 4 months ago. Now when I try to turn it on, both lights (red and red) are on . I haven't changed the configuration for several months, I have tried with two SD cards and my RPi can't read either of them.

I am running Raspbian Jessie on a RPi 2 B and I haven't updated for about 1 month.

I connected to my monitor screen and it only showed a black screen.

What can I do get my Pi working again?

Comment: This may sound silly, but make sure your SD card is seated properly.

Comment: I formatted the SD cards using *SDFormattter* and then I copied all content inside *NOOBS_V1.9.1*.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried different SD cards? If you did not power down safely, but instead just disconnected the power, you may have corrupted your SD card.

Revised answer :

On the Pi, the green light staying on means it couldn't read the initialization file `bootcode.bin` from the SD card. Check that the correct files are on the card and that it is FAT formatted, not EXFAT, and be sure that you are burning the latest os, as older Pi os's will not run on the newer Pi 3.(if applicable).

The red led should always be on as it indicates that the Pi is receiving power, it is likely that one of your SD card pins may have been bent, please ensure a solid contact.

Other than that I can not really help you, please mark this answer as correct if it has helped you debug or better understand your problem.

Comment: I have tried with a new raspbian installation with two SD cars, and I got the same *black screen*. SD cards worked fine when I tried in my laptop, so SD cards were not the problem. How can I power down safety ? When I was using my pi, I always executed *sudo power off* and then I disconnected the power.

Comment: @JasterTDCClan which two leds on your Pi are red? To my knowledge only 1 of the LEDs on the Pi marked `pwr` is red

Comment: One led is red, and other is green.

Comment: @JasterTDCClan does the green light blink before going solid? If so how many times?

Comment: When I power the pi, both of leds are on without blinking.

Comment: I formatted using FAT32 as a format, and I did it with *Win32DiskImage*.

Comment: @JasterTDCClan Your Pi is probably dead or you have bent sd card reader pins

Comment: @JasterTDCClan it may still be under warranty though, depending on how old it is, it also may have died due to static discharge from you handling it, you do only handle it from the corrners and always avoid making contact with the circuit(s) as you may discharge static, or short the board out.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me once, try to change the power supply and usb cable.

Comment: I tried with 3 differents usb cable, and I got the same result. @Joäo

Comment: What about power supplies? Have you tried another one? What's the max mA that your psu outputs (is recommended to have a 2A psu)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're experiencing a low current from your power supply, to verify it use a device like [this one](http://www.robiton.ru/product/12535) : it's bloody cheap and will serve you well for a long time. And - plug your SD card to another RPi or Linux and run `fsck`